# What bindings start with H-z?

Tags: key-bindings, help

When I type `H-z`, emacs waits for more input, so I assume
something is bound to `H-z` plus something else, only in this case
`C-h k H-z` also just waits for more input.  How can I find out
what is bound to what starting with `H-z`?

Comment: +1 for a question asking ***how to find out***... This is the best kind of question, especially for a tool like Emacs that gives you lots of ways to ask it for help. (Such questions should have the tag `help`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs has a special case for this, hitting the help character (default: either `C-h` or `F1`) after an incomplete key sequence will execute `describe-prefix-bindings` and show you possible commands starting with it.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the bindings that start with a prefix by pressing `C-h` or `<F1>` after the prefix.  In your case, pressing `H-z C-h`will list all bindings that start with `H-z`.

See this stackoverflow answer for more info about the convention that allows this to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330564/3101625